# When sending information to an external system, which system is reponsible for mapping information to the external system's domain?

Tags: design-patterns, integration

I have observed this situation in a couple of integration projects and I'm unsure if there is a standard approach in dealing with this problem.

Suppose we have a system **A** that integrates with a system **B**. Both systems share data and need to be in sync. Suppose A uses "**queues**" and these queues roughly map to "**groups**" in system B. So when any "**ticket**" gets created in a queue in A, that ticket is sent over to the corresponding group in B.

The question is, *which system should maintain a map of queues to groups*? A or B?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The general answer is that always the *client* should be responsible for preparing the data in appropriate form to call a service. If you design the system **B** it seems unreasonable to incorporate knowledge about every possible client system that will use **B**. To have good design you should aim for low coupling.

Consider the same case in a smaller perspective - usually utility classes provide some particular interface and don't expose *N* versions of each interface member to match every possible caller.

**2)** Sometimes though, exposed interfaces are created to accommodate different input structures (for example the `numpy` library in Python, which can perform linear algebra operations on native lists, arrays and matrices transparently). This seems limited to the cases when possible input structures are similar and well defined.

**3)** Third option often used in integration of large systems is to create intermediate applications called *Feeders* which are responsible for translating the data between the systems. In this solution each system remains "clear" of unneeded dependencies.